# How to upload pdf file in Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5

I want to upload with this controller:

```
if(Input::has('status-text'))
        {
            $text=e(Input::get('status-text'));
            $rules = [
            'status_text'=>'required|string',
            ];
            $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);


            if(Input::hasFile('status_image_upload'))
            {
                $rules['status_image_upload'] = 'image';
                $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
                if($validator->fails())
                {
                    $image = $request->file('status_image_upload');
                    $imageName = str_random(8).'_'.$image->getClientOriginalName();
                    $image->move('status_images', $imageName);
                    $userStatus = new Status();
                    $userStatus -> class_id = $id;
                    $userStatus -> status_text = $text;
                    $userStatus -> image_url = $imageName;
                    $userStatus -> type = 1;
                    $userStatus -> users_id = Auth::user()->id;
                    $userStatus -> save();
                    Flash::success('Your status has been posted');
                    return redirect(route('class',['class_id'=>$id]));
                }
            }
```

I know this controller will work for upload pdf. But i want to store another colunm `pdf_url`. Whats why i can view file and pdf in my blade page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May this help

Don't forget to add `'files'=>'true'` to the header of the form

```
{!! Form::open(array('url'=>'', 'method'=>'post', 'files'=>'true')) !!}
```

and then in the controller

```
if ($file = $request->hasFile('image')) {
            $file = $request->file('image');
            $filename = time() . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $destinationPath = public_path() . '/images/';
            $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);
            $support->image = $filename;
        }
```

and I suggest you use this package

[intervention/image](https://github.com/Intervention/image)